# lapply for pdf file in folder in R

Tags: r, pdf, lapply, pdftools

I wouldl ike to read all the .pdf on the desktop, but when I typed the code below, it showed

```
path_mot <- list.files("/Users/wangoe2345/Desktop", "*.pdf")
as.list(path_mot)
mot <- lapply(path_mot, 
              pdftools::pdf_text)
```

```
Error in normalizePath(pdf, mustWork = TRUE) : 
  path[1]="01_motivation_張翔淵.pdf": No such file or directory
```

"01_motivation_jason.pdf" is the pdf file on my desktop.
Thank for the kind response.

Answer (score 0):

Try using complete path with `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files`.

```
path_mot <- list.files("/Users/wangoe2345/Desktop", "\\.pdf$", full.names = TRUE)
```